# Using Eclipse with Kivy to develop for Android on Ubuntu

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu, kivy

Every guide I found either uses windows or mac. How can I develop using Eclipse on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PyDev for Eclipse. Check out http://pydev.org/.